# Phoenix - ** (ArgumentError) unrecognized time #<DateTime(2021-12-31T23:59:00Z)>

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using Timex.DateTime for working with datetimes through my project & so far it does the job.

However, I tried to make a custom builder for the Phoenix.HTML.Form for editing the datetime `publish_date` following [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/1.2.1/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#datetime_select/3):

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= label f, :publish_date, class: "control-label" %>
<br />
<%= datetime_select f, :publish_date, class: "form-control", builder: fn b -> %>
Time: <%= b.(:hour, []) %> : <%= b.(:min, []) %> : <%= b.(:sec, []) %>
<br />
Date: <%= b.(:day, []) %> / <%= b.(:month, []) %> / <%= b.(:year, []) %>
<% end %>
<%= error_tag f, :publish_date %>
```

I understand from the output that I work with different types, but I don't know how to transform them, I'm still learning Phoenix, so if you have a better approach for this problem that'd be also useful.

StackTrace:

```
      Request: HEAD /news/12/edit
  ** (exit) an exception was raised:
      ** (ArgumentError) unrecognized time #<DateTime(2021-12-31T23:59:00Z)>
          (phoenix_html) lib/phoenix_html/form.ex:966: Phoenix.HTML.Form.time_value/1
          (phoenix_html) lib/phoenix_html/form.ex:895: Phoenix.HTML.Form.datetime_select/3
          (estrada) web/templates/news_article/form.html.eex:41: anonymous fn/2 in Estrada.NewsArticleView.form.html/1
          (phoenix_html) lib/phoenix_html/form.ex:235: Phoenix.HTML.Form.form_for/4
          (estrada) web/templates/news_article/form.html.eex:1: Estrada.NewsArticleView."form.html"/1
          (estrada) web/templates/news_article/edit.html.eex:3: Estrada.NewsArticleView."edit.html"/1
          (estrada) web/templates/layout/app.html.eex:48: Estrada.LayoutView."app.html"/1
          (phoenix) lib/phoenix/view.ex:344: Phoenix.View.render_to_iodata/3
          (phoenix) lib/phoenix/controller.ex:633: Phoenix.Controller.do_render/4
          (estrada) web/controllers/news_article_controller.ex:1: Estrada.NewsArticleController.action/2
          (estrada) web/controllers/news_article_controller.ex:1: Estrada.NewsArticleController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
          (estrada) lib/phoenix/router.ex:261: Estrada.Router.dispatch/2
          (estrada) web/router.ex:1: Estrada.Router.do_call/2
          (estrada) lib/estrada/endpoint.ex:1: Estrada.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
          (estrada) lib/plug/debugger.ex:93: Estrada.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
          (estrada) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:34: Estrada.Endpoint.call/2
          (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
          (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

*EDIT:* This form works well when I create a new post with it, it crashes only when I edit a post with it, i.e. it works when the form submits the data to the server, this happens only when I populate the datetime field.

Comment: Looking at the time (December 31, 2021 at 11:59 PM) I'd guess that probably you're not fetching the fields from the DB correctly.

Comment: No I'm fetching them well, the input data is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `datetime_select` only supports a [limited number of formats of input](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/v1.2.1/lib/phoenix_html/form.ex#L613-L628), and `Timex.DateTime` does not match any of them.

You can manually convert the `Timex.DateTime` into a supported format and pass that:

Replace

```
<%= datetime_select f, :publish_date, class: "form-control", builder: fn b -> %>
```

with

```
<%= datetime_select f, :publish_date, value: Timex.to_erlang_datetime(model.publish_date), class: "form-control", builder: fn b -> %>
```

(Remember to replace `model` with your actual model.)

This workaround will hopefully not be needed in future versions of phoenix_html and timex when Elixir 1.3 is released [with a builtin DateTime struct](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/4383).

Comment: Thanks a lot, just to complete the part with populating the model, I didn't know how to do it, it should be as `f.data.publish_date`.

Comment: .. & also if someone else tries to implement this, it's important to do a null check for the field `f.data.publish_date`, since if you use the form with `new` the model's object will be empty.